# A query to select bigger value out of two which are stored in the same table, but in different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a following table named "Details":

| Shop_number | Reference_number | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 222222 | 48 | 263.900 |
| 222222 | 54 | 721.400 |
| 222223 | 48 | 125.100 |
| 222223 | 54 | 82.900 |
| 222224 | 48 | 329.800 |
| 222224 | 54 | 218.200 |

I would like to find/select all store number records where value of reference_number 48 is bigger than value of reference_number 54, so I would like 222223 and 222224 to be returned from my query.

I feel like it should be done with HAVING clause, but I'm not quite sure how to use it in this case. Problably also joining the same table may be advised to use in select query.

Comment: Do you really want to check hard coded for 48 and 54? This sounds very strange. Or do you need a more generic solution like checking the lowest and the highest reference number per shop number?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use `HAVING` for this

```
SELECT Shop_number
FROM   Details
GROUP  BY Shop_number
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Reference_number = 48 THEN Value END) > 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Reference_number = 54 THEN Value END)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, as you mentioned with self-join:

```
SELECT a.Shop_number, a.Value AS Value48, b.Value as Value54
FROM details a
INNER JOIN details b 
  ON a.Shop_number = b.Shop_number 
   AND a.Reference_number = 48 
   AND b.Reference_number = 54
WHERE a.Value > b.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a pivot aggregation approach:

```sql
SELECT Shop_number
FROM Details
GROUP BY Shop_number
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Reference_number = 48 THEN Value END) >
       MAX(CASE WHEN Reference_number = 54 THEN Value END);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just check that other value via subquery:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Shop_number
FROM Details d1
WHERE Reference_number=48
  AND Value > (
    select top 1 Value 
    from Details 
    where Shop_number=d1.Shop_number
      and Reference_number=54
  )
```